# A command, pushd does by argument as insensitive

Tags: case-sensitivity

how make `pushd` perform it by insensitive-case ?
tried to no avail

```
$ shopt -s nocasematch ; pushd pdf

bash: pushd: pdf: No such file or directory
```

Help guide the correct one, thanks.

Comment: `nocasematch` does not have an effect on command line arguments. See the [Bash manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/The-Shopt-Builtin.html#The-Shopt-Builtin). I don't see a way to accomplish what you want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `nocasematch` is used in:

> **nocasematch**
>
> If set, Bash matches patterns in a case-insensitive fashion when performing matching ***while executing case or [[ conditional commands, when performing pattern substitution word expansions, or when filtering possible completions as part of programmable completion.***

---

Albeit not recommended / could be some big caveats here. One hack is to use `nocaseglob`. Create a function and source it.

> **nocaseglob**
>
> If set, Bash matches filenames in a case-insensitive fashion when performing filename expansion.

For example here we set nocaseglob, witch would expand globs ignoring case.

Given argument `pdf` it globs `pdf*` and if length of both are the same do the push. Then reset `nocaseglob`

```bsh
nocasepush() {
    local g
    g=$(shopt -p nocaseglob)
    shopt -s nocaseglob
    for d in "$1"*; do
        if [ ${#d} -eq ${#1} ]; then
            pushd "$d"
        fi
        break
    done
    $g
}
```

Then doing `nocasepush pdf` should enter `PDF`.